# Placing links using the mail() function in PHP?

Tags: php, email, hyperlink

This is just a general formatting question. I'm attempting to place a link in the e-mail function, but I'm having trouble placing a period at the end of the link without having it become part of the link. I've tried concatenating a period at the end of it, but after the e-mail is sent it becomes part of the link.

```
"http://google.com" . ".";
```

Would I need to use html to do this? Specifically `<a href="">.</a>`

EDIT: Additional information:

```
$txt = "Please follow this link to the form: '<a href="http://google.com"></a>.';"
```

I put the rest of the code on the same line on a new line, but it still doesn't seem to register properly.

Comment: There is nothing in php's mail function that makes a plain text link into an actual link. So there is no telling what you mean. Perhaps some emailclient you are using is doing this?

Comment: `<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>.`

Comment: Basically I'm just trying to get a period at the end of a link, but the period becomes part of the link which is what I'm trying to avoid. `http://google.com` becomes `http://google.com.`

Comment: @Tim, am I able to embed that HTML code into a php file? It seems to make some of the code into a comment.

Comment: @StormyGraveyard yes, see my answer below.

Comment: Tried add "slash" eg. `$txt = "Please follow this link to the form: '<a href=\"http://google.com\"></a>.';"`?

Comment: Dont put in the period??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    echo '<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>.';
```

the period belongs outside of the `<a>` tag. Anything inside the `<a>` tag will be part of the link

**Update:** OP has updated the question.

You basically had a single quote where you didn't need one and you weren't escaping your double quotes. I prefer to use single quotes in my strings so I don't have to escape double quotes, and it's cleaner to read.

```
$txt = 'Please follow this link to the form: <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>.';
```

or, if you prefer using double quotes, you have to escape them because your string is enclosed in double quotes.

```
$txt = "Please follow this link to the form: <a href=\"http://google.com\">Google</a>.";
```

Comment: It seems to turn some of my code into a comment, I think it is because the link is in the middle of a bunch of other text included in the e-mail.

Comment: `//` or `/*` will turn your code into a comment. It's not because your link is in the middle of other text, it's because you're not concatenating it properly. Moving in and out of HTML and PHP can be a little tricky at times. :)

Comment: is there an escape I can use to prevent this? I tried adding additional slashes but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Why are you using slashes? What are you escaping?

Comment: Well adding the link into the $txt body for the email is causing the rest of the lne to turn into an HTML comment. I'm trying to locate a way to prevent the slashes in the link from registering as comments. I put additional info in the original post

Comment: updated my answer to reflect your new code.

Comment: The code posted worked - now it seems to not want to send the e-mail.

Comment: Glad that's working. Not sending the email is another issue for another question - it could be any number of things. Please mark my answer as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your headers (& sometimes the e-mail client the user is using), a link won't actually render as a link. Anyhow, here's the basic set-up.

```
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello. This is a <a href="http://google.com">link to Google</a>.';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

- [mail()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

It may also be worthwhile looking into a PHP library to send your e-mails. As it's super easy to send multipart e-mails. Take a look at [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org).